# Open Infopath in browser instead of Infopath filler

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath

Our current environment is SharePoint standard edition. As per the research done, I find that to open infoPath in browser requires SharePoint Enterprise edition. Is this true? or is there any possibility to open form in browser to fill out.

Comment: InfoPath services are not available on the standard version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is this true?**

Yes, it's correct, the Infopath service is only available with SharePoint Enterprise Edition, and can't be used in Standard edition. you can also check [the Feature Comparison between Standard and Enterprise](https://florianlaumer.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/sharepoint-2013-standard-vs-enterprise-vs-foundation-feature-comparison-matrix/).

**Is there any possibility to open it form in browser to fill out?**

Unfortunately, No!.

**What should you do?**

Use default forms, or develop your forms in the visual web part or use other 3rd tools like [formotus](http://www.formotus.com/16643/blog-infopath/microsoft-announces-future-infopath).

Answer (score 0):

Start the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell.

For Windows Server 2008 R2:

  On the
  **Start**
  menu, click
  **All Programs**
  , click
  **Microsoft SharePoint 2013 Products**
  , and then click
  **SharePoint 2013 Management Shell**
  .

For Windows Server 2012:

  On the
  **Start**
  screen, click
  **SharePoint 2013 Management Shell**
  .
  If
  **SharePoint 2013 Management Shell**
  is not on the
  **Start**
  screen:
  Right-click
  **Computer**
  , click
  **All apps**
  , and then click
  **SharePoint 2013 Management Shell**
  .

***Run the below command***

```
Set-SPInfoPathFormsService -AllowUserFormBrowserRendering $true
```